# Cannot see the acronyms list

Tags: acronyms, overleaf

I ma using a template in overleaf and I have this chapter for achronyms:

```
\chapter{List of acronyms}

{\small
\begin{acronym}[XXXXXXXX]
  \Acro{GNU}     {\acs{GNU} is Not Unix}
  \acro{OO}      {Orientación a Objetos}
  \acro{RPC}     {Remote Procedure Call}
  \acro{BDD}     {Behaviour Driven Development}
\end{acronym}
}
```

The problem is that in the results I see only the title of the chapter and a blank page. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}
\chapter{List of acronyms}

{\small
  \begin{acronym}[XXXXXXXX]
    \acro{GNU} {\acs{GNU} is Not Unix}
    \acro{OO}  {Orientación a Objetos}
    \acro{RPC} {Remote Procedure Call}
    \acro{BDD} {Behaviour Driven Development}
  \end{acronym}
}
\end{document}
```

Notice that I simply replaced `\Acro{GNU}` by `\acro{GNU}`.

[image]

Comment: hmm amazingly on compiling a second times the bold `GNU!` becomes non-bold `GNU`. But I simply don't know what `\acs` stands for...

Comment: what is the form of definition with square brackets here `\acs[linebreak penalty]{acronym}` for examples? and what is this here `[XXXXXXXX]`

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}
\chapter{List of acronyms}

{\small
  \begin{acronym}[XXXXXXXX]
    \acro{GNU} {\acs{GNU} is Not Unix}
    \acro{OO}  {Orientación a Objetos}
    \acro{RPC} {Remote Procedure Call}
    \acro{BDD} {Behaviour Driven Development}
  \end{acronym}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  You can highlight your code and click `{}` to format it correctly.  It would also help to identify what you changed to solve the problem.  Was it just `\Acro{GNU}` becoming `\acro{GNU}`?  Did you make a different change from the other answer that's a year older?

Comment: Thanks for posting, but this isn't really an answer; it's just some code.  Say *what* you're doing and *why* it works, so this will be useful to everyone.